# DateFormat with custom month names

Tags: flutter, dart, date-formatting

I have a list of 12 month names, let's say `['AAA', 'BBB', ...]`. In reality, they are kind of historical, so not included in any typical locale.

Now I want them to be included into my `DateFormat('yMMMMd')` instead of the normal names. **I am not able to build the date string manually** like

```
var myDateStr = myMonthName + ' ' + myDay + ', ' + myYear; // US
var myDateStr = myDay + '. ' + myMonthName + ' ' + myYear; // DE
```

because **I want to keep the format of the chosen locale** nonetheless. The day/month/year order changes with the chosen locale, which I want to keep. I just want to replace the month name. A RegExp replace or similar is not easily possible, I guess, because of the different date formats and language specific month names.

Expected result:

- For chosen `US` locale: `AAA 1st, 2022`
- For chosen `DE` locale: `1. AAA 2022`
- of course, every other locale format must be supported...

Do you have any ideas?

Is it possible to just insert custom month names into DateFormat object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had an idea, which seems to work:

```
var dateStr = DateFormat('yMMMMd', myLocale).format(myDate);
var monthName = DateFormat('MMMM', myLocale).format(myDate);

return dateStr.replaceFirst(monthName, 'AAA');
// or
return dateStr.replaceFirst(monthName, myHistoricalNames[myDate.month - 1]);
```

1. First create the normal date string to receive the locale's date format.
2. Calculate another date string which only includes the locale's month name. Now I know the string which I need to replace in `dateStr` no matter which language I choose.
3. Replace the month name with my custom month name.